# Can't seem to fix this Error after updating Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated Android Studio and I can't load all of my project due to this erros: All the updates are already done updating.

```
Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc3
<a href="install.build.tools">Install Build Tools 23.0.0 rc3 and sync project</a>

Loading SDK information...
Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-23.0.0-preview'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.
```

Gradle;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.systematixnote.basicmathoperation"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

Comment: Could you post your app build.gradle pls?

Comment: @Want2bExpert I have included it, thanks

Comment: Someone seem to have beat me to the answer, but I posted likely answer anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known bug of the recent build. This bug is reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175087).

**Temporary solution:**
Change `buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"` to `buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"` in your `build.gradle`

**Note: Hopefully this bug will be fixed in the next update.**

Answer (score 2):

@Mohammad beat me to it. 
As he said change 
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
To 
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

Comment: No problem thanks will definitely help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Same error with a project I downloaded from github. I had to set mine to `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"` for it to work.